# Angular 5 SSO read request header

Tags: angular, http, single-sign-on

I need to read an attribute from the SSO request header and pass as part of the call to my Angular 5 application.

I can see the attributes if I use the following JSP code:

```
Enumeration eNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while (eNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String name = (String) eNames.nextElement();
    String value = normalize(request.getHeader(name));
})
```

I just don't know how to get this information in my Angular 5 application from the request header?

Comment: you can use oidc-client.js for sso it's working great for me

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 4.3+,

You can use angular HTTP module to get request headers.

```
http.get<any>('url', {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(request => {
    console.log(request.headers.get('YOUR-HEADER'));
});
```

Please see documentation here : https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Headers have to be exposed by your webserver.